# Platform independent delay timer

Tags: c++, c, delay, platform-independence

#### Problem

I originally posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789295/rising-or-falling-edge-triggered-delayer-for-simulink-models) question which was apparently something that did not meet my customer spec. Hence I am redefining the problem:

To understand the problem a bit more, the timing diagram on the original post can be used. The delayer needs to be platform independent. To be precise, I run a job scheduler and apparently my current delayer is not going to be compatible with it. What I am stuck with is the "Independent" bit of the delayer. I have already knocked out a delayer in SIMULINK using `Probe` (probes for Sampling Time) and `Variable Integer Delay` blocks. However, during our acceptance phase we realised that the scheduler does not comply with such configuration and needs to be something more intrinsic and basic - something like a while loop running in C/C++ application.

#### Initial Solution

What I can think of a solution is the following:

1. Define a global and static time-slice variable called `tslc`. Basically, this is how often the scheduler runs. The unit could be in seconds
2. Define a function that has the following body:

   ```
   void hold_for_secs(float* tslc, float* _delay, float* _tmr, char* _flag) {
        _delay[0] -= tslc[0];
        if (_delay[0] < (float)(1e-5)) {

           _flag[0] = '1';     

        } else {

              _flag[0] = '0';            

        }

   }
   ```

Users please forgive my poor function-coding skilss, but I merely tried to come up with a solution. I would really appreciate if people help me out a little bit with suggestions here!

**Computing Platform**
Windows 2000 server

**Target computing platform**
An embedded system card - something similar to a modern graphics card or sound card that goes along one of the PCI slot. We do testing on a testbed and finally implement the solution on that embedded system card.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that what you are asking for is sensibly possible without platform-specific OS support.  What magnitude of delay are you seeking, uS or hours?

Comment: @MartinJames     I should have clarified that we do have an OS running. Our testbed uses Windows 2000 server OS. However, we have a specialised embedded system in the form of a card (like graphics card or sound card) that will be used as the final system. And my delay magnitude varies from ms to s - if that makes sense.

Comment: General advice - write a stand-alone question, instead of referring to another post. The question itself, without links, should explain what you want.