# How to create a counter in simulink

Tags: counter, simulink, counting, zero

I would like to count how many times my signal goes to zero. For example having an impulse signal as input I want a variable which counts how many times the impulse goes to zero.

I´m becoming crazy thinking of something....can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code you've tried and give a more specific question about what isn't working as expected?

Comment: I tried to use the counter limited block. The problem is that the latter keeps counting meanwhile the signal is zero. Instead I want just 1 when the signal is zero and it has to keep 1 until the signal goes to zero again. Then it will become 2 and so on

Answer (score 2):

figure 1 is a pulse counter model
[image: pulse counting model]]
and figure 2 is scope output which shows for 5 input pulses we get counter output as 5
[image: Scope output]

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17862816/5037322) that might help. There are loads of ways to implement a counter, but a good way I've used before is to use a rising/falling edge detect. I don't have the library on my computer so I can't test this [Edge Dectector](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/edgedetector.html) but I've used one similar in the past for just this problem. It will output a single sample time impulse when it detects a given condition, which in your case would be a signal going to zero. You can then use with a memory block and an add to implement a counter. See below:

[image]