# Simulink counting switching frequency?

Tags: simulink, pwm, simscape

I need to create some kind of counter, that counts how many times all of the transistors(signal_1, signal_2, signal_3, signal_4) I have used turn ON (and OFF) **per second**. I need to show the difference in switching frequency between 2-level and 3-level inverter, the signal is PWM. I have no clue how to do it, I'm really lost here.

This is my schematics (just 1/3 of it, other 2/3 is just doubled this).

[image]

Comment: Isn't the frequency for a pwm constant? So you basically take a rising edge detector and measure the time between two events? https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55456-measure-the-frequency-of-given-input-square-wave

Comment: I need to count all the switches, where 1 count counts as TURN ON and other cound counts as TURN OFF.

Comment: Counting is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/q/35319945/2732801